# Can An Android Application Be Launched Without a Main Activity?

Tags: android, launch

I have verified that an App does not need a Main Activity, and in fact does not need any activities. Thanks for the responses on this.  But here is another question. Is there any way to launch an application without a main activity declared?   If the answer is no, then I have a follow up, can the MAIN action be removed from the application at runtime after launch so that the app no longer has a MAIN activity after launch?  Or even can the activity itself be entirely removed from the application at runtime if it is no longer needed.

Comment: PS by Launch I mean from the users application list like any other app.

Comment: If your app doesn't have/need any activities why do you want to 'launch' it? What does it do? If you essentially want to turn something on/off then an AppWidget could do that job.

Answer (score 2):

The definition of "the users application list" is "the list of all activities supporting the MAIN action and LAUNCHER category". Hence, if you do not have an activity supporting the MAIN action and LAUNCHER category, nothing from your application will appear in "the users application list".

> can the MAIN action be removed from the application at runtime after launch so that the app no longer has a MAIN activity after launch?

You can disable the activity component via `PackageManager`. This may not immediately remove it from the launcher, as home screens sometimes cache this information. And, it will break any shortcuts the user made to this activity. In general, this is not a recommended technique.

> Or even can the activity itself be entirely removed from the application at runtime if it is no longer needed.

No.

Comment: Ok.  Then if I make make the Main Activity hidden, I could launch it still?  If so then if I could tell that the request to onStart(Intent) was a launch I could direct the user to a launch only Activity, the rest of the time I could keep it hidden.  Is this possible to detect if the Activity is being started on launch vs. being resumed etc.  Can this hidden state be dynamically applied

Comment: Is the above scenario possible using android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay".  It all hinges I guess on if I can detect if the MAIN activity is getting launched or is being activated for some other reason.

Comment: I know the question sounds a bit convoluted, but the main point is I want the MAIN for launch, and first view, after that the MAIN activity is an unwelcome guest in my application, until I request it again from somewhere else like a widget.  Even then I really don't probably need to goto a Main anymore,but another page would be fine.

Comment: @Androider: "Then if I make make the Main Activity hidden, I could launch it still?" -- not if you disable it. "I want the MAIN for launch, and first view, after that the MAIN activity is an unwelcome guest in my application, until I request it again from somewhere else like a widget." -- bear in mind that users have repeatedly and loudly indicated that they don't like this. They will consider your application to be broken if they cannot figure out how to run it.

Comment: the way you run it is to launch it right?  what i am talking about is not having an activity reappear that the user is no longer using.  thats what i am trying to prevent.  others have had the same probem of the main activity showing up when least expected, and i think users don't like that either.

Comment: @Androider: As I have pointed out before and will continue to point out, that is a bug in your app. I have handed you two separate projects that properly implement app widgets that update themselves. One (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/34-AdvAppWidget/LunchList) even has a launcher activity and a few other activities besides. None of those activities magically pop up "when least expected". You are trying to work around your own bug. Fix your bug.